# How to remove markdown syntax and output only plain text in Flutter

Tags: regex, string, flutter, markdown

Does anyone know how to remove Markdown syntax from a string in Flutter? I looked into packages like "markdown" and "flutter_markdown" but did not find any functions to do that. Or should I create an own dart function and use regex to convert it to plain text?

Edit: I "created" a method to remove markdowns. The question is if this is enough or did I miss anything else?

````
String removeMarkdown(String markdown) {
  // Replace bold text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\*\*(.+?)\*\*"), r"\1");

  // Replace italicized text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r"_(.+?)_"), r"\1");

  // Replace strikethrough text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r"~~(.+?)~~"), r"\1");

  // Remove inline code blocks
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r"`(.+?)`"), "");

  // Remove code blocks
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r"```[\s\S]*?```", multiLine: true), "");

  return markdown;
}

void main() {
  String markdown = "**bold** _italic_ ~~strikethrough~~ `inline code` ```code block```";
  print(removeMarkdown(markdown)); // Output: "bold italic strikethrough inline code code block"
}
````

Edit2: it does not look complete, like captions are missing.

Comment: You mean you want remove html tags from string?

Comment: I am not using any html tags in my markdowns. An example which ones should be removed: "**bold** _italic_ ~~strikethrough~~ `inline code` ```code block```

Comment: You could use the package:markdown to create an abstract representation of your parsed input, and then translate that to text in whatever manner you wish.  That'd be a lot better than ad-hoc regular expressions on the input, since markdown has a lot of interesting edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

````
String removeMarkdown(String? markdown) {

  // Replace bold text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*'), '');
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp('__(.+?)__'), '');

  // Replace italicized text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp('_(.+?)_'), '');
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\*(.+?)\*'), '');

  // Replace strikethrough text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp('~~(.+?)~~'), '');

  // Replace inline code blocks with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp('`(.+?)`'), '');

  // Replace code blocks with plain text
  markdown =
      markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'```[\s\S]*?```', multiLine: true), '');
  markdown =
      markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'```[\s\S]*?```', multiLine: true), '');

  // Remove links
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)'), '');

  // Remove images
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'!\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)'), '');

  // Remove headings
  markdown =
      markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^#+\s+(.+?)\s*$', multiLine: true), '');
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\s*=+\s*$', multiLine: true), '');
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\s*-+\s*$', multiLine: true), '');

  // Remove blockquotes
  markdown =
      markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\s*>\s+(.+?)\s*$', multiLine: true), '');

  // Remove lists
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(
    RegExp(r'^\s*[\*\+-]\s+(.+?)\s*$', multiLine: true),
    '',
  );
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(
    RegExp(r'^\s*\d+\.\s+(.+?)\s*$', multiLine: true),
    '',
  );

  // Remove horizontal lines
  markdown =
      markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\s*[-*_]{3,}\s*$', multiLine: true), '');

  return markdown;
}
````

Answer (score 1):

BOr1 answer didn't work for me

```
  // Replace bold text with plain text
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*'), '');
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(RegExp('__(.+?)__'), '');
```

This actually ends up removing the whole matched pattern

What worked for me is

```
markdown = markdown.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*'), (match) => match.group(1) ?? "");
markdown = markdown.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('__(.+?)__'), (match) => match.group(1) ?? "");
```

This also takes care of what OP was trying to do with `r"\1"`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

```
String removeMarkdownSymbols(String text) {
// Regular expression to match Markdown symbols including '#'
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'[*_~`#]');
// Replace Markdown symbols with an empty string
return text.replaceAll(regex, '');
}
```